# AspectJ Load Time Weaving takes too much time

Tags: java, scala, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have created an executable jar of my `scala` application. I am trying to use `AspectJ Load-Time-Weaving`. The aspectj is working as expected, however, it is taking a huge amount of time to start the jar file after the LTW.

My AOP.xml is as below:

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.app.module.aspect.WorkflowInterceptor"/>
    </aspects>

    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <dump within="com.app.*"/>
        <!--<include within="com.app.common.features..*"/>-->
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

When I run the jar file as

```
java -javaagent:aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

The jar file starts after 15 min, sometime even 30 min. I tried to reduce the aspectj weaving by using `include` but not working. If I do not provide `dump`, the aspect is not getting invoked at all.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

**EDIT:**
I removed the `<dump>` and used `<include within ..>`. It is working, but still taking a lot of time (5 min )

Comment: -javaagent:aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar makes it compile time weaving. So you're weaving twice I think. I never had to use dump advice to make it work.

Comment: @sturcotte06 how is it compile time weaving? javaagent is used while loading/running the jar right?

Comment: Are you using spring? If I remember correctly, you need to specify a special ClassLoader for load time weaving. The java agent is the special compiler that rewrite your code at compile time (compile time weaving).

Comment: no, i m not using spring. My app is in scala.

Comment: "In addition the dump element can be used capture on disk byte-code of woven classes for diagnostic purposes both before, in the case of those generated at runtime, and after the weaving process." You don't need that. Also, I just read that the class loader is included in the java agent. I guess it's ok to specify it like you do.

Comment: Add the  -showWeaveInfo flag into your weaver's options.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. If I remember correctly, I tried removing dump, and added include, but was getting some issues. Dont remember exactly as I have tried out many different things.

Comment: I removed dump and added include. It is working as expected, but it is taking almost 5 min to start the jar file.

Comment: It's because you're weaving too much. How many classe are contained within the packages starting with com.app

Comment: Yeah, there are too many classes. I tried to reduce the scope by giving multiple include statements, for some reasons it was not weaving at all. I can give multiple include lines in aop.xml, right ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Be the more precise possible.

Comment: Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please. Maven project on GitHub is preferred. Or at least show us your aspect(s) and provide us with a few numerics such as the number of classes in your `com.app` package (incl. subpackages).